# Can a local max = an absolute max?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Probably a very straightforward answer, but I am wondering if an absolute max on a graph can equal a local max?

Comment: If we take $f(x) = -x^2$, what do you conclude from this example?

Comment: When there is unique local maximum that local maximum is also equal to the absolute maximum. So there are plenty of examples.